# Counting dimension of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ containing three disjoint lines

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

Assume $k$ is algebraically closed field of char zero.
Let $l_1,l_2,l_3$ be three disjoint lines in $\mathbb{P}^3_k $.
The dimension of the $k$-vector $\operatorname{Homog}_2 
k[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]$ of degree $2$ homogeneous polynomials in
$4$ variables is $10$ by usual [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) trick. We can associate to every such homogeneuos
polynomial $P_2(x)$ of degree $2$ a hypersurface $H_{P_2} \subset
\mathbb{P}^3_k $ which equals on each affine chart $D(L)$ with linear polynomial $L= \sum a_i x_i$ the vanishing set
of points of the obtained polynomial after localization in $L$.

Question: Is there a combinatorical argument (in spirit of stars and bars trick) why
the subvector space of $\operatorname{Homog}_2 
k[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]$ consisting of all homog polynomials of degree $2$ which have
associated hyperplanes containing all three disjoint lines
$l_1,l_2,l_3$ is non zero.

Can it be derived more cenceptionally?

Say we have an arbitrary point $p \in \mathbb{P}^3_k $ and a
line $l \subset \mathbb{P}^3_k $. What is the dimension of
subspace of $\operatorname{Homog}_2 
k[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]$ which have associated hyperplanes
containing point $p$? Or the line $l$? Or both? If we know it how
to approach combinatorically this problem we can also ask the
natural question about the dimension of subspace of homog polynomials
which have hyperplanes contain two oder more points, lines
or more dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Similary can such combinatorial argument be generalized to say $\mathbb{P}^n $, $\operatorname{Homog}_m 
k[x_0, x_1, ..., x_n]$ with $m \le n$ and one asks what is the dimension of $k$-subspace of polynomials which have associated hyperplanes all containing certain linear subspace $L_1 \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ or some subspaces $L_1,..., L_r \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a beautiful subject that gets hard very quickly. To answer your initial question: notice that if we fix a line $\ell \subset \mathbb P^3$, it meets every hyperplane; the intersection is either a point, or the entire line (obviously this latter case is when the line lies in the hyperplane). On the other hand, if we fix a point $p \in \mathbb P^3$, there is a codimension $1$ subspace of hyperplanes which contain $p$ (in the Grassmannian/dual projective space $\mathbb P^{3\vee} = \mathbb G(2,3) = G(2,4)$ of hyperplanes in $\mathbb P^3$). Since a different point $q$ determines a different codimension $1$ subspace, their intersection has codimension $2$. A third point results in a codimension $3$ linear space, which in $\mathbb P^3$ is a point: in other words, $3$ general points determine a $2$-plane, which you've known since high school.

The space of quadrics containing a given line $L$ can be computed by supposing that we have homogeneous coordinates $(W:X:Y:Z)$ on $\mathbb P^3$ such that $L$ is $W=X=0$. Then the equation for such a quadric has the form $Q = W\cdot L_1(W,X,Y,Z) + X \cdot L_2(W,X,Y,Z)$ where $L_1,L_2$ are linear forms. The (projective) space of linear forms is $3$-dimensional, so overall you have a $6$-dimensional space of quadrics containing $L$. This has codimension $3$ in the $9$-dimensional projective space of quadrics. Choosing two other general lines, you get two more codimension $3$ subspaces, so the intersection is codimension $9$ (codim. is additive over intersections of generic subspaces) a.k.a. dimension $0$, hence we get not just non-emptiness of the space of quadrics containing the three lines, but in fact that the quadric is unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two comments: you argued on a specific line
$L$ given by $W=X=0$. For arbitrary line $L_1$ we can simply perform 
certain projective transformation of $P^3$ mapping $L_1$ to $L$
and apply what we already know for $W =X=0$ line, since we are only interested
in dimensions and our counting is intrinsically compatible with differerent
choices of coordinates (=transformations), that's why it suffuce to discuss only
line with $W=X=0$ right?

Comment: And for a point instead of a line (say by previous projective trafo
argument that's sufficient to discuss only
$P=(0:0:0:1)$ ) we apply strategy and obtain
$Q_P = W \cdot L_1 + X \cdot L_2 + Y \cdot L_3$ with linear $L_i$,
so $9$-dim and so on?

Comment: Everything you've commented is in the right direction. You always have to be vigilant about vector space dimension vs. projective space dimension, but you seem to have processed the relevant ideas.

Comment: As you said to be vigilant about vector space dimension vs. 
projective space dimension do you refer to the fact that we can 
associate to the space of degree $m$ homogeneous polynomials in $n$ variables
$\operatorname{Homog}_m k[x_1,...,x_n] $ a linear system of associated
hypersurfaces which form naturally a projective space with dimension
which is one less then that one of $\operatorname{Homog}_m k[x_1,...,x_n] $?
Or did you maybe intend there to stress another point in your last comment?

Comment: That's precisely what I mean. At each step in these kinds of calculations, you want to be 150% sure whether it's the vector space of polynomials or the projective space of hypersurfaces that you are discussing.